# Java simple arithmetic

Tags: java

I'm sorry, but this program hacienod java eclipse luna and mars, the problem is to have the times of "lunes" and so on but once I insert brand me as 109 times. I need help, please.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dias {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner Scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
    int car=0;
    int repl=0;
    int repm=0;
    int repi=0;
    int repj=0;
    int repv=0;
    int reps=0;
    int repd=0;
    int i;

    do {
        System.out.println("introduzca caracteres");
    car = Scanner.next().charAt(0);
    if(car == 'l'){ 

         System.out.println("lunes");
         repl+='l';
    }else {
        if (car=='m'){
            System.out.println("martes");
            repm+='m';
        } else {
        if(car == 'i'){         
            System.out.println("miercoles");
            repi+='i';
        } else {
        if(car=='j'){
            System.out.println("jueves");
            repj+='j';
        }
            else {
                if(car=='v'){
            System.out.println("viernes");
            repv+='v';
                }
                else {
                    if(car=='s'){
                    System.out.println("sabado");   
                    reps+='s';
                }
                    else {
                        if(car =='d'){
                            System.out.println("domingo");
                            repd+='d';
                        }
                        else {
                             if(car !='l' || car !='m' || car !='i' || car !='j'|| car !='v' || car !='s' || car !='d'){

                                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                                    }
                        }



                    }
                }
            }

        }
        }
    }
    }


while(car !='*');
    System.out.println("*");

    System.out.println("veces repetidas de lunes:" +repl );
    System.out.println("veces repetidas de martes:" +repm );
    System.out.println("veces repetidas de miercoles:" +repi);
    System.out.println("veces repetidas de jueves:" +repj );
    System.out.println("veces repetidas de viernes:" +repv );
    System.out.println("veces repetidas de sabado:" +reps );
    System.out.println("veces repetidas de domingo" +repd );
    }
}
```

Comment: TO be honest your question is not clear to me. Please provide us what did you input? What do you expect?

Comment: Could you please narrow it down to the part, where your problem is? eg.: where simple arithmetic fails?

Comment: ok sorry , the problem is , if i enter the letter l the program show me "lunes" and times introduced, but if only I introduced one time the program show me 109 times intoduced

Comment: Your error lies here: `repl+='l';` Char `l` is 108.

Answer (score 0):

it would be on your variable declaration

```
char car;
```

`Scanner.next().charAt(0);` gives you `char` and you are comparing with character in your if-else.

And on your last `else`

```
if (car != 'l' && car != 'm' && car != 'i' && car != 'j' && car != 'v' && car != 's' && car != 'd' && car != '*') {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```

Comment: mmm no , i change int for char and i havethe same problem

Comment: char car; with no initialization runs perfect for me. And on you last clause I think there is a logical consideration you should make for "*" character. By the way switch-case would really give you a readable code.

Comment: introduzca caracteres
l
lunes
introduzca caracteres
*
ERROR
*
veces repetidas de lunes:108
veces repetidas de martes:0
veces repetidas de miercoles:0
veces repetidas de jueves:0
veces repetidas de viernes:0
veces repetidas de sabado:0
veces repetidas de domingo0

Comment: enter characters
l
Monday
enter characters
*
ERROR
*
times repeated Monday: 108
times repeated Tuesday: 0
sometimes repeated from Wednesday: 0
times repeated Thursday: 0
times repeated Friday: 0
times repeated saturday: 0
times repeated domingo0

Comment: I change the initialization

Comment: but if i only enter once the character L they showme 108 times

Comment: i put in spanish(my lenguage) and english

Answer (score 0):

I hope I interpreted your question properly. I wasn't too clear. From what I gather, you want to increase the count of those specific variables by 1 each time. If I am correct, then the problem in your code is very clear. You wrote:

```
repl+='l';
```

Here it will add the ASCII decimal representation for the character 'l' to the variable repl. The ASCII code for 'l' is 108. To correct the error, all you need to is change all the similar codes to something like this:

```
repl ++;
```

Here is the complete code with the changes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dias {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int car = 0;
        int repl = 0;
        int repm = 0;
        int repi = 0;
        int repj = 0;
        int repv = 0;
        int reps = 0;
        int repd = 0;
        int i;

        do {
            System.out.println("introduzca caracteres");
            car = Scanner.next().charAt(0);
            if (car == 'l') {

                System.out.println("lunes");
                repl++;
            } else {
                if (car == 'm') {
                    System.out.println("martes");
                    repm++;
                } else {
                    if (car == 'i') {
                        System.out.println("miercoles");
                        repi++;
                    } else {
                        if (car == 'j') {
                            System.out.println("jueves");
                            repj++;
                        } else {
                            if (car == 'v') {
                                System.out.println("viernes");
                                repv++;
                            } else {
                                if (car == 's') {
                                    System.out.println("sabado");
                                    reps++;
                                } else {
                                    if (car == 'd') {
                                        System.out.println("domingo");
                                        repd++;
                                    } else {
                                        if (car != 'l' || car != 'm'
                                                || car != 'i' || car != 'j'
                                                || car != 'v' || car != 's'
                                                || car != 'd') {

                                            System.out.println("ERROR");
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        while (car != '*');
        System.out.println("*");

        System.out.println("veces repetidas de lunes:" + repl);
        System.out.println("veces repetidas de martes:" + repm);
        System.out.println("veces repetidas de miercoles:" + repi);
        System.out.println("veces repetidas de jueves:" + repj);
        System.out.println("veces repetidas de viernes:" + repv);
        System.out.println("veces repetidas de sabado:" + reps);
        System.out.println("veces repetidas de domingo" + repd);
    }
}
```